# Non-greedy regex in emacs like this

Tags: regex, emacs

The text is like this:

```
 /mnt/alphabets....../alphabets..../dataset974/974_summits.bed
```

**I want to select this part:**

```
 /mnt/alphabets....../alphabets..../dataset974
```

Using regex I-search, I typed in:

```
 /mnt.*[0-9]*?
```

But the selected part is:

```
/mnt/alphabets....../alphabets..../dataset974/974_summits.bed
```

Does anyone how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that `/mnt.*` greedily eats up the whole text, from `/mnt` to the end of the line. What should be non-greedy is the first `*`. Try this:

```
/mnt/.*?[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **groups**? For an example in following `regEx`, group 1 gives you the required result.

```
(/mnt(?:.*))/
```